# Mijireh / Klarna Checkout - Are they safe?

Tags: payment-gateway

A friend asked me to take a look at two checkouts, [Mijireh](http://mijireh.com) and [Klarna](http://klarna.com), and see if they were **safe**.

First off, does anyone have any experience with either of these checkouts?  Can you provide some information on whether or not they are **safe**?

Second, what constitutes a **safe** checkout system?  I mean, obviously these sites are going to be storing valuable information such as credit card & banking info and will be responsible for transactions worth some amount of $$$... So, how do I judge whether or not these checkouts are safe?

Also, is there any advantage to using a payment gateway **other than Paypal?**  I guess they probably charge less for transactions than Paypal does...

I tried Googling for information on Mijireh but couldn't find much, just pages and pages of nonsense.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A few clarifications about Mijireh.

1. Mijireh is not a payment gateway themselves.  They still require that you use an existing payment gateway such as Stripe, PayPal Pro, etc. for processing credit cards.  Mijireh provides a secure, PCI Compliant environment to collect credit cards and send the to your payment gateway.
2. Mijireh actually does NOT store credit card information on their servers, ever.  It only securely transmits the credit card information to your configured payment gateway (such as Stripe, PayPal Pro, Authorize.net, etc.)

Hope that helps clear things up a bit.

Joey, Mijireh Team

Comment: Cheers Joey, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Klarna Checkout is about giving credit to consumers so they can pay after delivery. Klarna takes both fraud and credit risk in the transaction.

If the customer wants, he can prepay the order, that will take place through a PSP connected to Klarna. Klarna Checkout does not store any credit card information in it's own system.

Klarna collects and stores transaction details (cart content) and customer details. All details are shared with the merchant.

Klarna Checkout is at the moment only available in Sweden but other countries will follow. https://klarna.com/sv/salj-med-klarna/vara-tjanster/klarna-checkout contains information in Swedish.